# How to join one row on whole table

Tags: sql, join, vertica

I have tho tables: regions with m rows and categories with n rows. As a result, I need a table where one row in regions joins on all rows in categories:

```
region 1    category 1
region 1    category 2
...
region 1    category n
...
region m    category 1
region m    category 2
...
```

region m    category n

My DBMS is HP Vertica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for a `cross join`:

```
select r.*, c.*
from regions r cross join
     categories c;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `CROSS APPLY`

```
SELECT 
        *
FROM
        regions 
CROSS APPLY
        categories
```

Comment: as far as I know, there is no cross apply function in Vertica DBMS (at least I could not find it in documentation)